# How to extract non-nans from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have read through many posts but I am still not able to figure out the following. How can I extract non-nans from a pandas DataFrame? Eg.:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Women': {0: 28, 1: 42, 2: 52, 3: 62},
 'Men': {0: 46.0, 1: 55.0, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 'Girls': {0: 40.0, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
 'Boys': {0: 47.0, 1: 49.0, 2: 35.1, 3: np.nan}}

)
```

The output would be a `list` or `dict` looking like:

```py
[[28, 42, 52, 62], [46.0, 55.0], [40.0], [47.0, 49.0, 35.1]]
```

I can do this with looping over columns and dropping nans:

```py
x=[]
for col in tmp.columns:
    x.append(list(tmp[col].dropna()))
```

But I was curious if there is some nicer way without the for loop or using some pandas features to make it fast and nice. Ideally a one-liner since this should be in a bigger function so as simple, readible and short as possible :).
Thanks

Comment: `without the for loop` , `fast and nice`, `simple`, `readible and short as possible`. What are we shopping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea with list comprehension:

```
L = [[y for y in x if pd.notna(y)] for x in tmp.T.to_numpy()]
print (L)
[[28.0, 42.0, 52.0, 62.0], [46.0, 55.0], [40.0], [47.0, 49.0, 35.1]]
```

Without looping is possible, but not sure if better performance if large data:

```
L = tmp.stack().groupby(level=1, sort=False).agg(list).tolist()
print (L)
[[28.0, 42.0, 52.0, 62.0], [46.0, 55.0], [40.0], [47.0, 49.0, 35.1]]
```

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! Thank you very much. One more question -- what's happening to the types? In both your examples it converted all to floats (I reckon it's the ```pandas``` and ```numpy``` safe choice) unlike in my solution where it preserves the original type. It is not important to me in regards to the original question and its solution, I'm just curious if they could be preserved :).

Comment: @MyWork - I think reason is some missing values in columns, so if at least one `NaN` in column it convert numbers integers to floats.